# Continue the application even if a thirdparty application fails

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have a thirdparty exe file name Projtest.exe and  using a  c# console application written by myself for running the Projtest.exe through commandline.
i was able to succeed in writing the application,but my issue is that due to some unknown reasons Projtest.exe stops working and throws an error window.My application is stucking at this point.What i want is to continue my application if Projtest.exe throws an error window.How can i do that.Part of my code is given below.

```
try
{

   var pro = new Process
   {
      StartInfo = {
                    Arguments = string.Format("Projtest.exe  {0} {1} ", arg1, arg2)
                   }
   };

  pro.Start();

  pro.WaitForExit();
  var exit = pro.ExitCode;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can to do is regularly check if 'pro' is responding say every 10 seconds. 
You can do this simply with a timer or you could create a thread to do it.
Also it is worth checking for exit here as well so you don't block your application.
Here is an example with a timer.

```
       static Timer appCheck = new Timer();
    static Process pro;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        appCheck.Interval = (10000);                        // set timer interval in ms   
        appCheck.AutoReset = true;
        appCheck.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(appCheck_Tick);

        try
        {

            pro = new Process
            {
                StartInfo =
                {
                    Arguments = string.Format(@"Projtest.exe"),
                    FileName = string.Format(@"Projtest.exe")
                }
            };
            pro.Start();  // starts your program
            appCheck.Start(); // starts the timer to keep a watch on your program
            while (true) // this just keeps your console window open. if you use waitForExit your application will be blocked and the timer won't fire. 
            {
            }
            //pro.WaitForExit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    static void appCheck_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!pro.HasExited)
        {
            if (pro.Responding == false)
            {
                appCheck.Stop();                // stop the timer so you don't keep getting messages
                Console.WriteLine("Not responding");

            }
        }
        else
        {
            appCheck.Stop();                // stop the timer so you don't keep getting messages
            Console.WriteLine("exited");    
        }

    }
```